# Which version of zlib should I use with visual c++ on visual-studio-2005?

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2005, version

I was wondering if anybody knew what versions of gzstream are compatible with visual-studio 2005.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.1.3 works fine in VS2K5 here at work...